# Using z-transforms to solve difference equations.

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions, recurrence-relations

I am faced with the following question and would appreciate any help you may be able to offer: It is not homework, I know the first and second shift theorems and based on the other examples I have done, I know you start by taking the z-transform of the equation, then factor out X(z) and move the rest of the equation across the equals sign, then you take the inverse z-transform which usually involves partial fractions and it should yield the answer given. Cheers

Use z-transforms to solve:

$$2x[k+1]-x[k]=2^k \,,\quad x[0]=2$$

The answer is:

((2^k)/3)+5(((0.5)^k)/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by definition we have 
\begin{align*}
   X(z) &= \sum_{k\ge 0} x[k]z^{-k}\\\
        &= 2 + \sum_{k\ge 0} x[k+1]z^{-(k+1)}\\\
        &= 2 + (2z)^{-1}\sum_{k \ge 0} \left(2^{k} + x[k]\right)z^{-k}\\\
        &= 2 + (2z)^{-1}\sum_{k\ge 0} 2^{k}z^{-k} + (2z)^{-1}X(z)\\\
        &= 2 + (2z)^{-1} \frac 1{1 - \frac 2z} + (2z)^{-1} X(z).
\end{align*}
Now oyu can solve for $X(z)$.